# MP android chart displaying float values at X-Axis of Horizontal bar Chart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MP chart for displaying reviews, everything is working fine except that the the X-axis values are displaying as a floating value (for number of particular type of review).

This is the code I am using:

```
     BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet(properties));
            chart.setData(data);
            chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false); // hides horizontal grid lines inside chart
            YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
            chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false); // hides horizontal grid lines with below line
            leftAxis.setEnabled(false); // hides vertical grid lines  inside chart
            /*chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);*/ // for animating reviews display
            chart.invalidate();
            chart.setClickable(false);
            chart.setDescription("");    // Hide the description
            chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
            chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
            chart.setPinchZoom(false);

            leftAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet(Properties properties) {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();

        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(properties.getRating10().intValue(), 0);
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(properties.getRating20().intValue(), 1);
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(properties.getRating30().intValue(), 2);
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(properties.getRating40().intValue(), 3);
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(properties.getRating50().intValue(), 4);
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Asset");
        barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("12.0");
        xAxis.add("4.0");
        xAxis.add("4");
        xAxis.add("4");
        xAxis.add("4");
        return xAxis;
    }
```

Here I am setting data to horizontal bar chart.

[image]

I want the red circled values to be in integers instead of float.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have got it solved (thanks again Philipp), This is the solution

Create Your own value formatter class that implements the given ValueFormatter

this is my class:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter{
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return Math.round(value)+""; 
    }
}
```

Then set the value Formatter to your BarData:

```
BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet(properties));
data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

That's it  this is the output-

[image: image without decimal]

Comment: I tried this option. But still the values i get are not int values. I have entries as integer value. If i have 4 tasks as completed i.e entry as (4,1) the value shown on bar is  10. Y so?@Manikanta

Comment: Unless i see your value formatter and the way you are setting values to it i can comment on this.

Comment: can you please help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735219/how-to-add-entries-in-mpandroid-chart   @Manikanta

Comment: nice thinking +1 :)

Answer (score 7):

The [ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) interface let's you display whatever you want inside the chart. More decimals, less decimals, strings, ...

Comment: Thanks a Ton @philipp Jahoda I have got it.

Comment: can you help me on how to write text inside each bar? like, Inside Green bar 5 star , orange bar 2 star like that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this in kotlin

```
barData.setValueFormatter(object :ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                return "${ value.toInt() }"
            }
        })
```

Use this if you are using Java

```
 barData.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String  getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return String.valueOf((int) value);
            }
        });
```