# How to implement horizontal rating bar chart in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, bar-chart, rating

**how to get this type of graph**?

I want to design and implement a horizontal **rating bar chart** in my app like the image below.
I followed several tutorials, but I'm not able to get a proper solution.
[image: rate bar chart]

Please suggest links or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work for you try this way

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-chart-example-mp-android-chart-library/

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDescription("My Chart");
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Aditya. how could i hide inner lines from bar chat?

Comment: @pb123 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821912/mp-android-chart-displaying-float-values-at-x-axis-of-horizontal-bar-chart

Comment: Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart/59543575?noredirect=1#comment105256325_59543575

Answer (score 5):

Use this library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Add this to your app **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
}
```

[image]

Comment: This library is not working with negative values please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart/59543575?noredirect=1#comment105256325_59543575

Answer (score 1):

Here is actual **solution 2017** after the MPAndroidChart library changed.

**1. Add to build.gradle**

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

And to your app build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    }
```

**2. Add chart element to your template:**

```
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**3. Add to Fragment onCreateView (or Activity onCreate)**

```
    HorizontalBarChart chart = (HorizontalBarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    BarDataSet set1;
    set1 = new BarDataSet(getDataSet(), "The year 2017");

    set1.setColors(Color.parseColor("#F78B5D"), Color.parseColor("#FCB232"), Color.parseColor("#FDD930"), Color.parseColor("#ADD137"), Color.parseColor("#A0C25A"));

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

    // hide Y-axis
    YAxis left = chart.getAxisLeft();
    left.setDrawLabels(false);

    // custom X-axis labels
    String[] values = new String[] { "1 star", "2 stars", "3 stars", "4 stars", "5 stars"};
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(values));

    chart.setData(data);

    // custom description
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("Rating");
    chart.setDescription(description);

    // hide legend
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    chart.animateY(1000);
    chart.invalidate();
```

**4. Finally add some custom classes and functions to the Fragment\Activity with chart:**

```
    public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private String[] mValues;

    public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
        this.mValues = values;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mValues[(int) value];
    }

}

private ArrayList<BarEntry> getDataSet() {

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();

    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(1, 4341f);
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(2, 3121f);
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(3, 5521f);
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(4, 10421f);
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(5, 27934f);
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);

    return valueSet1;
}
```

**5. My result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: I referred your code and it is working fine but Instead of 5 labels on XAxis , it is setting 6 labels as per your screenshot and I want only 5 labels , will you please help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As i cannot comment Aida Drogan solution i post this as another answer:

In order to limit labels to 5 and to not overlap take a look at this function: 
Restricting Intervals
In case you are using a formatter based on array indices (like above), it makes sense to restrict the minimum interval of your axis to "1":

```
axis.setGranularity(1f); // restrict interval to 1 (minimum)
```

This will prevent the formatter from drawing duplicate axis labels (caused by axis intervals < 1). As soon as the "zoom level" of the chart is high enough, it will stop recalculating smaller intervals.

Answer (score 1):

**2019 solution**: Here is a library that does exactly what you are looking for without any hassle:

[Library and setup](https://github.com/Inconnu08/android-ratingreviews)

[image]

In your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

In your app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.Inconnu08:android-ratingreviews:1.0.0'
```

#### Usage

> java

```
        RatingReviews ratingReviews = (RatingReviews) findViewById(R.id.rating_reviews);

        int colors[] = new int[]{
                Color.parseColor("#0e9d58"),
                Color.parseColor("#bfd047"),
                Color.parseColor("#ffc105"),
                Color.parseColor("#ef7e14"),
                Color.parseColor("#d36259")};

        int raters[] = new int[]{
                new Random().nextInt(100),
                new Random().nextInt(100),
                new Random().nextInt(100),
                new Random().nextInt(100),
                new Random().nextInt(100)
        };

        ratingReviews.createRatingBars(100, BarLabels.STYPE1, colors, raters);
```

> xml

```
    <com.taufiqrahman.reviewratings.RatingReviews
        xmlns:bar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rating_reviews"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"
        bar:animation="true"
        bar:max_value="100"
        bar:show_label="true"
        bar:spaces="0dp"
        bar:text_color="#333333"
        bar:text_size="10sp"
        bar:width="15dp" />
```

**All colors and style can be changed to fit. More details [here](https://github.com/Inconnu08/android-ratingreviews) if needed.**